# When using net -W WORKGROUP -n HOSTNAME getting "Invalid Command"

Tags: debian, command-line, samba, net

Running Debian Linux with `samba`, `smbclient` and `samba-common-bin` packages installed.  I am trying to run the command (as root for now and adding response)

```
root@machine:/# net -W WORKGROUP -n HOSTNAME
Invalid command: net
Usage... and all the options
```

and I am getting the response "Invalid Command" even though this should be the correct usage.  Running `man net` gets me all the man pages and `net help` gives all possible  options including the the above.

The intent is to configure a Debian Mini-Linux USB stick for a Clonezilla cloning operation.  Our Intrusion Detection System is set up to recognize the workgroup as WORKGROUP and CLONEZILLA (hostname) along with a particular brand of NIC card to allow it on the network.

After more research, I found that smb.conf is configured for workgroup = WORKGROUP and I have put CLONEZILLA in the hostname file in the stick.  I was going to use the command line above to set those in the Clonezilla environment.  Now I have to test against the IDS.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided qualifiers (`-W` and `-n`) but no action for the `net` command to execute. It responds by giving you the list of actions that it can perform, for example, `net status shares`

(Update your question to tell us what you're trying to achieve and maybe someone here can help you with the appropriate command.)